# How to install Wireless drivers?

Tags: drivers, wireless

I went around Google and looked on YouTube for some videos, but for whatever reason, nothing worked. I tried going into "Additional drivers" and switching the driver that way, but nothing actually changes. It just stays stuck either applying the changes or nothing happens.

I currently have an ether net connection set up temporarily, so I am able to access the web. However, I want this fixed as soon as possible.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z049.00 Wireless Mini PCIe Card [103c:1507]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Update: The output to lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z049.00 Wireless Mini PCIe Card [103c:1507]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: You're going to have to tell us your WiFi card model.

Comment: To find how to install your wireless card driver you first need to find out what chip it has, after finding out you should try to find an alternative way to connect to the Internet (such as LAN connection), then you'll need to google your card chip name and search for linux driver, it'll probably have a git repository that will have all the explanations for how to install it in the description. if you'll provide your wireless card brand name & model we might try to help you to find out what you're looking for.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: This is rather a commentary than an answer.

Comment: agreed, but for some reason I can't comment yet (I must have at least 50 points)

Comment: Thank you. But, how do I check for my wireless card brand name and model?

Comment: @Moohooses Please read my command under your question and provide the output.

Comment: What is the command. I don't see it. (Sorry, I'm new to this forum.)

Comment: Can you see my comments under YOUR QUESTION? And this is not a forum. It is a question @ answer site.

Comment: Never mind. Found it.

Comment: This is the output I got:

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z049.00 Wireless Mini PCIe Card [103c:1507]
 Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT POST OUTPUT TO COMMENTS. Do what I asked.

Comment: You told me to provide the output. And I did.

Comment: I've done that for you. Now see the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer.

Go to System Settings -> Software & Updates.

Make sure that `main`, `universe`, `multiverse` and `restricted` repositories are checked.

Then remove DVD disks as software sources, then

run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

It looks like you used some daily build to install the system, not the final release. But that does not matter much if you do all the previous actions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation and all comments on the answer have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42722/discussion-on-answer-by-pilot6-how-to-install-wireless-drivers).