# WiFi connections problems in Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS

Tags: wireless, iphone

I installed one week ago Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but I can't yet connect to WiFi via router. I can connect with my iPhone in router mode, but when I try to connect to other WiFi it is impossible. Here you can see my WiFi card.

```
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c  latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:81 memory:82400000-82407fff memory:82000000-823fffff
```

What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` I suspect that you already have the correct driver. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does your router access point configured to 2.4 or 5g? Does other devices can connect your router wifi?

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of propiary drivers not install by default
i think it was answered here [How to install Wireless drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800509/how-to-install-wireless-drivers)